# Add video player to a GLB model with controls

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to add a video player in a GLB model mesh using Three.JS. Although this can done using VideoTexture, I'm trying to add all of the controls that a video player has by default.

Here's a code snippet by using VideoTexture:

```
let video = document.createElement( 'video' );
video.loop = true;
video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
video.muted = "muted";
video.load(); 
video.src = videoD;
video.controls = true

let texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
let material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );

// and then use this material as the material for the glb child mesh
```

The problem with the above approach is I can't add controls. I'm using react currently, so another way
is to use HTML component and try to load that in place of the mesh, here's the approach for that using react refs

```
<>
  <primitive ref={stall_ref} object={glb.scene} />
    <Html>
      <ReactPlayer ref={react_player_ref} id="widget2" url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' />
    </Html>
</>
```

and then use this ref to modify the video player position

```
// I'm actually not sure what I'm doing here

react_player_ref.current.position.copy(meshChild.position)
react_player_ref.current.quaternion.copy(meshChild.quaternion)
react_player_ref.current.matrix.copy(meshChild.matrix)
react_player_ref.current.matrixWorld.copy(meshChild.matrixWorld)
react_player_ref.current.scale.copy(meshChild.scale)
react_player_ref.current.rotation.set(meshChild.rotation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet might be to build a UI yourself out of a bunch of planes, and use [raycasting](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) or [libraries such as this](https://github.com/jasonChen1982/three.interaction.js) to register clicks.

Since your threeJS video texture uses a video dom element, it should be easily controllable using JavaScript.

```js
const DemoScene = () => {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...

    // setup UI planes
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 20, 32)
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xffff00,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
    const playUIPlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    scene.add(playUIPlane)

    // ...

    // setup raycasting, see documentation…
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()
    raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, camera)
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)

    // ...

    // check if/which UI has been intersected
    const video = ref.current
    const { object } = intersects[0]

    if (object === playUIPlane) video.play()
    if (object === pauseUIPlane) video.pause()
    if (object === incVolumeUIPlane) video.volume += 0.2

    // ...
  }, [ref])

  return (
    <>
      <video ref={ref} width="320" height="240" controls loop>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <canvas />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!, though I guess this wouldn't solve the problem of positioning the video player exactly at the place of mesh, your answer will basically only help out with video controls, let's say a plane is made and then controlling based on events on that plane right?

Comment: You can [group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) multiple geometries (glb model and planes) and apply transformations on all of them at once.

Comment: It’s also possible to add planes before exporting the glb in your 3D modeling program, then accessing the separate meshes in the `loader.load()` function: `const mesh = gltf.scene.children[ 3 ];`

Comment: Hey, sorry, could you back this up with a possible example? neither the video player is mesh nor it is a model, it is an HTML element, how would you apply transformations to the html element so that it aligns completely with a mesh

Comment: Check out the [video texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture). It uses a html video element. You can add the video texture to a basic material, i.e. `const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(videoElem)`, then `const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture })`. Give this material to any mesh (f.e. a plane geometry), and you'll have a video playing in 3D space [like so](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_video). However, this does not come with video controls. See my original post for a possible solution on how to add controls to your scene.